# Word for "Total amount of all purchases"

Tags: word-request

Is there a single word (or a short phrase) for "Total amount of all purchases"?
Example. List of purchases a company has made from us:

[image]

Total amount of purchases here would be 1430 + 150 + 2050 = 3630. In this context, I can name it simply "Total" since the reader has seen the table and knows what I'm about. But how would these 3630 be named from any context? Say, we're talking about a company and I tell you "That company's valuable to us since its ... is 3630"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any given ledger, invoice, receipt etc, the final, aggregated sum may be called the '*grand total*'. This term is used especially when there are *subtotals* at various points throughout, as in your document when each figure contributing to the grand total is perhaps a totalled figure itself.

There isn't really a single term to refer to 'all the purchases ever made' by a particular customer that you could use in the context of your statement. I would probably say something like:

- That company is valuable to us as a customer, *their business to date has totalled* $3630.
- They are a valuable customer to us, *their historic purchases total* $3630.
- They are a valued customer. *They've spent $3630 with us to date*.

Comment: Does this work without context? Could you say "That company's valuable for us, since its grand total is £3630".

Comment: @JamesK fair point, I had overlooked that part of the question and focused on the ledger they showed. Updated.

Comment: *The company is valuable **to** us because they purchase over thirty-five hundred Pounds worth of our product every month.*